# difference in memory usage between `$stdin.getc` and `$stdin.read`

Tags: ruby

My question is - I have an assumption that `$stdin.read` loads whole input string in memory at once, while `.getc` loads only one character at a time.

Is this correct, I'm not sure?

Answer (score 0):

[IO#read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-i-read):

> Reads length bytes from the I/O stream.
>
> *length* must be a non-negative integer or `nil`.
>
> If *length* is a positive integer, it tries to read *length* bytes without
>   any conversion (binary mode). It returns `nil` or a string whose *length*
>   is 1 to *length* bytes. nil means it met EOF at beginning. The 1 to
>   length-1 bytes string means it met EOF after reading the result. The
>   *length* bytes string means it doesn’t meet EOF. The resulted string is
>   always ASCII-8BIT encoding.
>
> If *length* is omitted or is `nil`, it reads until EOF and the encoding
>   conversion is applied. It returns a string even if EOF is met at
>   beginning.
>
> If *length* is zero, it returns `""`.
>
> If the optional outbuf argument is present, it must reference a
>   String, which will receive the data. The outbuf will contain only the
>   received data after the method call even if it is not empty at the
>   beginning.
>
> At end of file, it returns `nil` or `""` depend on *length*. `ios.read()` and
>   `ios.read(nil)` returns `""`. `ios.read(positive-integer)` returns `nil`.

[IO#getc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-i-getc):

> Reads a one-character string from ios. Returns nil if called at end of
>   file.